# Struts 2 override resource messages keys

Tags: struts2, resourcebundle

Consider this

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="messages/default,messages/customize" />
```

And `default.properties` content is

```
label.sample = Default Sample
```

And the customize.properties content is

```
//Duplicate key
label.sample = Customize Sample
```

Calling `<s:text name="label.sample">` will result in `Customize Sample` If we review the above strust i18n this seems correct behavior as we first defined default and then the customize, so the keys in customize properties will override the keys in default.

Now we try to override the customize messages dynamically. So

```
   <!--The customize is removed -->
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
            value="messages/default" />
```

In some where like an startup servlet, we add customize messages as:

```
LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/customize");
```

This will not work! As alternative if we remove default from i18n property and do it as below, we will get the customize value

```
LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/default");
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/customize");
```

Is it possible to keep the list of default properties in xml and only add customize ones at run time

---

**This why we need it** 
We are developing AND hosting a web application which is sold to lots of customers. The application has a default message. It is possible that ONE of our customers wants to change some of application default messages while the others not. So we have a folder of customize messages and let each bank override its own messages.

We have below folder structure for customers:

```
+messages
  -resources_fa_IR.properties
  -resources_en_US.properties 
+customer1
   -customize_fa_IR.properties
   -customize_en_US.properties
+customer2
   -customize_fa_IR.properties
   -customize_en_US.properties
```

And in StartUpSerlvet

```
//Set customer customize messages
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/" + activeCustomer+"/customize");
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't call `clearDefaultResourceBundles` if you want to add resource. What exactly is your `StartUpSerlvet` and how it configured?

Comment: For `clearDefaultResourceBundles` you are right. The `StartUpSevlet` is very simple `ServletContextListener` gets the active customer from some property files and call `LocalizedTextUtil`. If you think it helps I can put the code here!

Comment: Does it work for you if you do it in `postInit` method?

Comment: For struts 2.5.12 and future refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327141/migrate-from-struts-2-3-33-to-struts-2-5-12-localizedtextutil-is-removed/45399766#45399766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your custom `ServletContextListener` runs before S2 adds default resource bundles from `struts.custom.i18n.resources`.

The solution is to execute `LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle` from somewhere what is executed after the S2 added all default resource bundles.
For example you can extend `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` and do it in `postInit` method.

Comment: You are correct about the order and using `postInit` solved it!