# Using Struts2 i18n feature in Quartz jobs

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, quartz-scheduler, resourcebundle

Our web application is based on Struts2. We get all message resource by using struts `getText()` in actions and Struts2 `<s:text name=""/>` in JSP.

The application also has some Quartz job which run at certain times. Is it possible that we use Struts2 classes in Quartz jobs to get the proper message resources from message bundles.

Please consider that we configured *lots* of message files with Struts and also, we use Struts2 ability to override certain message resources ([Struts 2 override resource messages keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137603/struts-2-override-resource-messages-keys)) so we prefer to use Struts2 way to get i18n messages instead of java build in feature.

Comment: What is not working with the linked question, and how it's different?

Comment: Dear @RomanC the linked question is why we need struts to manage our resources. Well, let me ask this way, can I use struts `getText()` function in quartz job? and how?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking, the answer:  probably you can't, but some API will return results that you might not want.

Comment: You know about `LocalizedTextUtil` class. Why you cannot use it?

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks, It worked!  Please send it as answer so I mark it as correct answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the methods in `LocalizedTextUtil` class to get localized messages from resource bundles in Quartz jobs.

For example take a look at:

```
LocalizedTextUtil#findDefaultText(String aTextName, Locale locale)
```

or

```
LocalizedTextUtil#findText(Class aClass, String aTextName, Locale locale)
```