# Migrate from Struts 2.3.33 to Struts 2.5.12 LocalizedTextUtil is removed

Tags: java, localization, struts2, migration

We tried to migrate from Struts 2.33 to Struts 2.5.12.

We used `LocalizedTextUtil` in our application directly.

I found that the `LocalizedTextUtil` is removed from `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil`. I tried to search but could not find any thing

I found some classes like `StrutsLocalizedTextProvider`and `GlobalLocalizedTextProvider` but it seems they are not what I can use them.

I have reviewed [migration-guide](https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-guide.html) but could not find any comment about it.

Which alternative is there?

Comment: Depends what for and where you're using it. You can inject `LocalizedTextProvider`. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4813.

Comment: I am using it to override struts 2 resource bundles keys. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137603/struts-2-override-resource-messages-keys You have helped me about that 2 years a go :)

Comment: :) Again it depends on where do you want to use this. But, now you can create new instance of `GlobalLocalizedTextProvider` add bundles to it and use it. You can also wrap it in some bean and inject it.

Comment: It did not work! I tried `LocalizedTextProvider provider = new GlobalLocalizedTextProvider(); provider.addDefaultResourceBundle('messages/resources')` but the resource is not added. Should I use another technique.

Comment: I set an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4829. Meanwhile I see that https://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-set-a-global-resource-bundle.html is not valid any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The struts.xml should be set as:

```
<constant name="struts.xworkTextProvider" value="DefaultTextProvider" />
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider" name="DefaultTextProvider" class="utils.MyTextProviderFactory" scope="default" />
```

And `CustomStrutsTextProviderFactory` could add bundles

```
public class MyTextProviderFactory implements TextProviderFactory {

protected LocaleProviderFactory localeProviderFactory;
protected LocalizedTextProvider localizedTextProvider;

@Inject
public MyTextProviderFactory(LocaleProviderFactory localeProviderFactory, LocalizedTextProvider localizedTextProvider) {
    this.localeProviderFactory = localeProviderFactory;
    this.localizedTextProvider = localizedTextProvider;
    
    this.localizedTextProvider.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/label");
    this.localizedTextProvider.addDefaultResourceBundle("messages/customerA/label");
    
}

@Override
public TextProvider createInstance(Class clazz) {
    TextProvider instance = getTextProvider(clazz);
    if (instance instanceof ResourceBundleTextProvider) {
        ((ResourceBundleTextProvider) instance).setClazz(clazz);
        ((ResourceBundleTextProvider) instance).setLocaleProvider(localeProviderFactory.createLocaleProvider());
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public TextProvider createInstance(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    TextProvider instance = getTextProvider(bundle);
    if (instance instanceof ResourceBundleTextProvider) {
        ((ResourceBundleTextProvider) instance).setBundle(bundle);
        ((ResourceBundleTextProvider) instance).setLocaleProvider(localeProviderFactory.createLocaleProvider());
    }
    return instance;
}

protected TextProvider getTextProvider(Class clazz) {
    return new TextProviderSupport(clazz, localeProviderFactory.createLocaleProvider(), localizedTextProvider);
}

protected TextProvider getTextProvider(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    return new TextProviderSupport(bundle, localeProviderFactory.createLocaleProvider(), localizedTextProvider);
}
```

}

Complete credits to @LukazLenart https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4829

Comment: hi, I am trying to implement this solution as I am migrating from Struts2 2.3.36 to Struts2 6.1.2.1, can you please explain where to use this MyTextProviderFactory class? is it enough to wire it in the struts xml as you have shown, or do I need to use this class in place of the StrutsLocalizedTextProvider to register the bundles?

Comment: my application has around 19 modules, and with the older version of struts2 we were adding the defaultResourceBundles in the init class of all the modules using LocalizedTextUtil, but since it is removed, I replaced it with StrutsLocalizedTextProvider. We have a custom implementation of TextProvider which internally uses the DefaultTextProvider class, but after the version upgrade i keep getting NPE on DefaultTextProvider class because the `protected LocalizedTextProvider localizedTextProvider` field is null. Sorry if I am not making much sense, as I am quite new to the framework

Comment: @soumitragoswami ask it as a new question and add link here

Comment: added as a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830874/localizedtextutil-alternative-in-struts2-6-1-2-1

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`StrutsLocalizedTextProvider`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/StrutsLocalizedTextProvider.java) or [`GlobalLocalizedTextProvider`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/GlobalLocalizedTextProvider.java). They have some *util* api, however it's marked as deprecated. Happily, it's documented in the javadoc.

<sub>I'm referencing source code from the repo because I was unable to find these classes in javadoc for Struts 2 Core 2.5.11-SNAPSHOT API</sub>